# How to append getJSON's results to a div each time I click the loadmore button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, getjson

On load of a page my `getJSON` call displays its output to a div (called myDiv).

Now I want to add a button at the end of the page and when the user clicks that button, I want to make another call to `getJSON`, but this time I want to increment the page_number by one, each time the user clicks on the button and displays the new result at the end of the previous results. Could you guys show me how I can do this?

```
<head>
  <script>
    //var counter = 1;
    $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=https://www.myothersite.com/getit.php?page_number=+counter&type=TopVideos&sortBy=newest&callback=?', function(data){
      var siteContents = data.contents;
      //writes to textarea
      document.myform.outputtext.value = siteContents;
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=siteContents;
      $('#loadingimg').hide();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="MainDiv">
    <div class="MainContent">
      <div class="ContentWidth">
        <div id="JSListVideo" class="VideoList">
          <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

And the button code:

```
<div class="MoreButtonSection">
  <div class="RedButton">
    <span class="LeftEnd"></span>
    <span class="Centre">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="seemore();" title="See more">see more</a>
    </span>
    <span class="RightEnd"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering I would advise you to stick with one approach, either jQuery syntax or Javascript. I think you want pagination code. The code below might be of some use to you.

I'd like to give you some idea below about how it can be done. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
//initialize page number to 1 default
var pagenumber=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
  //load first page records on page load
  getResult(pagenumber);
});

//pass pagenumber to function to fetch correct page records
function getResult(pagenumber){
  $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=https://www.myothersite.com/getit.php?page_number='+ pagenumber +'+counter&type=TopVideos&sortBy=newest&callback=?', function(data){});
  //after every call increment page number value
  pagenumber++;
}
$('btnLoadMore').click(function(){
  //simply call getResult
  getResult(pagenumber);
});
```

I can't locate the `seemore()` function in your code. Perhaps you want something like this. Your HTML must be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return seemore();" title="See more">see more</a>
```

JS must be:

```
function seemore(){
  counter++;
  return false;
}
```

`counter` must be a global variable so that it is accessible. No idea about your URL:

```
http://anyorigin.com/get?url=https://www.myothersite.com/getit.php?page_number=+counter&type=TopVideos&sortBy=newest&callback=?
```

I think it should be:

```
http://anyorigin.com/get?url=https://www.myothersite.com/getit.php?page_number='+ counter +'&type=TopVideos&sortBy=newest&callback=?
```

Comment: can you please add some comments in your code? will be helpful.

Comment: i cant make my button work with your click event ! should i place your first code inside another function and call it seemore?

Comment: Thanks i fixed the issue i just removed $('btnLoadMore').click(function(){getResult(pagenumber);}); and added a function: function seemore(){pagenumber++;getResult(pagenumber)'} and used my button <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="seemore();" title="See more">see more</a>

Comment: good. if my post helped you. dont forget to mark it as answer . so that others can be benefitted.

Answer (score 2):

First of all wrap code inside `$(document).ready();`.

Now you need to create a `click` event for the button so that when the button is clicked, it will call `getJson` and then you can append data to the desired div, because right now your code will **just run at load time**.

**Example**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  $('button').on('click',function() {
    $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=https://www.myothersite.com/getit.php?page_number=+counter&type=TopVideos&sortBy=newest&callback=?', function(data) {
      var siteContents = data.contents;
      document.myform.outputtext.value = siteContents;
      $("myDiv").html(siteContents);
      $('#loadingimg').hide();
    });
    counter++;
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks can you tell me how to modify my button so your click event work with it correctly ?

Comment: @user1788736 you need to add unique ID to your button and then just replace `$('button')` with `$('#buttonID')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add value to the current value. look at bellow:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += siteContents;
```

Comment: thanks fore reply .But how to increment the page number each time i click the button to call getjson(default page number i want it to be one since that is the value that executes when page loads for first time ?